# Does this hit the db everytime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have in:

```
config/initializers/foobar.rb
```

which has:

```
$foos = User.where(:foo => true).pluck(:id)
```

In my app when i call `$foo`, does it hit the db everytime?

Or does `$foo` only hits the db, on server start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing a scope (i.e. a set of criteria). However that scope will cache what it has loaded, so doing (for example) `$foos.each {|user| ...}` will only execute a query once, at the point of first use (not when assigned).

Some operations will always trigger a query though, for example `$foos.count` will always do a `select count(*)...` and others will depend on whether the scope has been loaded.

Lastly, further refinements on that scope would also hit the db, for example

```
$foos.order('blah').first
```

would trigger an new query each time it was used. It should be easy to see whether this is happening, although be wary when testing in irb: irb calls inspect on the results of expressions which causes the scope to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`$foos` is just a variable so it will only hit the database when it gets assigned.